# How can I allow all users to access only a certain type of entityform?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I need that all users (anonymous users too) have access to the submissions of a certain type of [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform).

I can set the permission *View any entityform submission* and it works but for all types of entityform. I also try with hook_access

How can I allow all users to access only a certain type of entityform but not for all types of entityform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution:

1. Alter the [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to call a new `access callback`
   for the entityform submissions:

   ```
   function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
       $items['entityform/%entityform']['access callback'] = '_mymodule_entityform_access';
   }
   ```
2. Check in the new `access callback` if the user is annonymous and the type of the entityform:

   ```
   function _mymodule_entityform_access($op, $entityform = NULL, $account = NULL) {
       global $user;
       if ($user->uid == 0 && $op == 'view' && isset($entityform) && $entityform->type == 'entityform_type') {
           return TRUE;
       }

       return entityform_access($op, $entityform, $account);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In filter. Just add.

> content: type => is one of (put check mark on all those content types
>   you want. )

And then add permission for that view.

The another way is.

- Go to permission section under people admin menu.
- Navigate to node section.
- You will find your content type name with VIEW,EDIT,DELETE permission
  with each users.
- Just put check mark for the user you want to them able too see.

Hope this will work.

Comment: I'm not using views or nodes. I'm using entityforms that are a type of entity.